# How to render default value in ant design checkbox using boolean?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ant-design-pro

I am trying to render a checkbox default value using ant-design.

Here is the data I want to render

```
plainOptions: [
    {
        name: "apple",
        is_enabled: "true",
    },
    {
        name: "orange",
        is_enabled: "true"
    },
    {
        name: "banana",
        is_enabled: "true"      
    },
    {
        name: "grape",
        is_enabled: "false",
    },
]
```

And here is the component :

```
                    <FormItemRow>
                        <Col span={24} style={colStyle}>
                            <FormItem label={'fruits'} colon={ false } style={{ marginBottom: 0 }}> 
                                <CheckboxGroup options={plainOptions} defaultValue={['true']}>
                                    {plainOptions.map(option => {
                                        return (
                                            <Checkbox key={option.label}>{option.label}</Checkbox>
                                        )
                                    })}
                                </CheckboxGroup>
                            </FormItem>
                        </Col>
                        </FormItemRow>
```

I get the result I want to see but the problem of using **defaultValue** inside of **CheckboxGroup** component is I get warning saying

```
Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `true`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version.
```

Seems like defaultValue works as just like **key** .

I also added **checked** inside of **Check** component and assigned boolean value but it does not work either.

How can I safely render a default value inside of checkbox without warning sign?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you used `option.label` instead of `option.name`, which gives undefined to all the keys, that's why you are getting warning of same keys.

```
<Checkbox key={option.name}>{option.name}</Checkbox>
```

If you are using **CheckboxGroup**, you don't need to use **Checkbox**.
You can use `CheckboxGroup` like this...

```
this.state = {
 plainOptions: ["apple", "orange", "banana", "grape"],
 checkedList: ["apple", "banana"] // Default Value
};
```

you will get array of values as param of the onChange event

```
onChange = (checkedList) => {
  this.setState({ checkedList });
}
```

```
<CheckboxGroup
  options={this.state.plainOptions}
  value={this.state.checkedList}
  onChange={this.onChange}
/>
```

In above example I used **checkedList** initial state for **default value** and assign latest state on onChange event.

Answer (score 2):

I actually think, that the key error comes from the fact that you used `option.label` instead of `option.name`. (which in this case should be undefined)

You have to differentiate between `value` and `checked`.
The `value` is the content, that will be returned if the checkbox is checked.

If you define a value, but the checkbox is not checked, it is not send along anyway.

Maybe turn the checkbox into a controlled input (meaning: you have a onChange event, that triggers a checked state) and pass your is_enabled value in `checked` prop.

```
<Checkbox key={option.name} checked={this.state.options[optionKey].is_enabled}>{option.name}</Checkbox>
```